Involution and inner product in semisimple group algebras
Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with characteristic zero and $G$ be a finite group. The group algebra $\mathbb{F}G$ is semisimple, and so
$$\mathbb{F}G=\mathbb{F}Ge_1\times\cdots \times \mathbb{F}Ge_k,$$
where $\{e_1,\cdots,e_k\}$ are the set of centrally primitive idempotents of $\mathbb{F}G$.
Let $W_i$ be a minimal left ideal of the simple algebra $\mathbb{F}Ge_i$. Then, $W_i$ for $1 \le i \le k$ are simple $\mathbb{F}G$-modules, or euivalently non-isomorphic irreducible $\mathbb{F}$-representation of $G$.
Now, I want to have a set of orthogonal (resp. unitary) irreducible representations of $G$ when $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ (resp. $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$). To this end, I think I need to define both appropriate involution and inner product in $\mathbb{F}G$, so that extending every orthogonal (resp. unitary) representation $\rho:G \to \text{GL}(W_i)$ to $\rho:\mathbb{F}G \to \text{End}(W_i)$ becomes *-algebra homomorphism. Is that so?
If the answer is yes, I define them as follows. Let $\mathbb{F}$ have involution $\bar{}$ (trivial where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$ and complex conjugate where $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$). We define involution $^*$ in $\mathbb{F}G$ $$a^*=\left(\sum_ga_gg\right)^*=\sum_g\overline{a_g}g^{-1},$$
and inner product  $$\langle a, b\rangle=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_g a_g\overline{b_g}.$$
What is the next step? Do I need to show $$\langle au, v\rangle=\langle u, a^*v\rangle$$ for every $a \in \mathbb{F}G, u,v \in W_i$?
